# PHP object access using string

Tags: php, object, properties

I have an object in PHP with some very odd property names. I just need to know how to access a property when it's name is "//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type".

I found something that suggested

```
$object->{'//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type'};
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: If possible, please provide the object as serialized string. See http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works for me (PHP 5.2.9 and 4.4.4):

```
class A
{

}

$a = new A();
$p = '//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type';
$a->$p = 'wtf';
echo $a->{'//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type'};
echo $a->$p;
```

Comment: Very odd, I just get NULL with a string access.

However, assigning the string to a var and using that as in your last line works.

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Curious. Can I ask which version you're using?

Comment: You have a later version than I do. Thanks for letting me know. I'll keep a note of this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
get_object_vars($object)["//www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type"];
```